# Excel get row that contains value

Tags: excel

I have a table with multiple columns, the first column contains index values (0,1,2...N), think cluster ID's, and the remaining columns contain text strings, call these labels. The number of columns varies per row, but always contains at least one cell with a label, singular clusters. I have another table that contains a tag for each label, ie two columns with the first as the label and the second as the tag. I would like to have a table with index values and tags. Basically I need a formula that returns the row reference if a label is found in that row. I initially though some INDEX-MATCH combination or VLOOKUP would work, but all the examples I found have only one column in their search criteria, which is known before hand. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

I have tried replacing the labels with their tags, but one label can have multiple tags, so that did not work. Thnx in advance.

EDIT:

@Ben1344 almost has the right example, below is a small example ( I apologise for my naming convention)

```
Table 1 

0   A   C   D
1   E   G
2   Z   F   X
3   Y   


Table 2 

A   foo 
C   foo 
D   bar 
E   pikachu 
F   psyduck 
G   jigglypuff  
X   goldeen 
Y   psyduck 
z   foo 


Desired Table 

0   foo 
0   foo 
0   bar 
1   pikachu 
2   psyduck 
1   jigglypuff  
2   goldeen 
3   psyduck 
2   foo
```

Comment: Perhaps posting a small example using a much-reduced dataset together with your expected results would help clarify your query?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 2 tables and would like a third.

From your example, it looks like your desired table is effectively an additional column in your second table. The tags are largely a distraction. What needs to be done is:

Given table 1 and a label, get the index.

I can see two ways to approach this. OPTION 1:

VBA User Defined Function add the following routine to a module in VBA

```
Public Function FindInColumns(FindMe As Range, LookIn As Range) As Long
  Dim val
  val = FindMe.value
  Dim rng As Range
  For Each rng In LookIn
    If rng.value = val Then GoTo ExitLoop
  Next rng
ExitLoop:
  FindInColumns = rng.Row - LookIn.Row + 1
End Function
```

Assume table 1 is at A1:D4

Assume table 2 is at F1:G9

Put Table 3 at I1:J9

In cell J1 put `=G1`

In cell I1 put the following formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$4,FindInColumns(F1,$B$1:$D$4))
```

And drag down to the rest of the cells

OPTION 2:

(from: [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array.html))

Using only excel formulas:

Assume table 1 is at A1:D4

Assume table 2 is at F1:G9

Put Table 3 at I1:J9

In cell J1 put `=G1`

in cell I1 put the following formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MIN(IF($B$1:$D$4=G1,ROW($B$1:$D$4)-ROW($B$1)+1)))
```

This is an Array formula so when you enter it hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER to confirm.

Comment: Ok, I thought - "I have another table that contains a tag for each label, ie two columns with the first as the label and the second as the tag" meant there was only one tag per label. Is there the possibility of multiple labels per index and multiple tags per label?

Comment: @Ben1344 The same label can only occur on one line (ie each label has only one index, each index has possibly multiple labels, I effectively have disjoint clusters, where each line in Table 1 represents a cluster) Table 2 represents alternative ambiguous tags for the components of a cluster. I basically want to know which tag corresponds to which cluster.